# HABTM Relationship and Named Scopes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, relational-database, has-and-belongs-to-many

I've been working on this for a while now and I cant seem to find where there error.

I have a User Model(:name, :password, :email), and Event model(:name, :etc) and Interest model (:name) [>all singular<]

Then I created two join tables -> UsersInterests and EventsInterests; each not containing a primary key and only comprised of the user_id/interest_id and event_id/interest_id respectively. [>plural<]

My Models contain the HABTM Relationships as follows

```
user.rb => has_and_belongs_to_many :interests
event.rb => has_and_belongs_to_many :interests
interest.rb => has_and_belongs_to_many :users
               has_and_belongs_to_many :events
events_interests.rb => has_and_belongs_to_many :interests
                       has_and_belongs_to_many :events
users_interests.rb => has_and_belongs_to_many :users
                      has_and_belongs_to_many :interests
```

Whew..ok So I wanted to created a named_scope of that find all the events that share interest with a particular user. Here is some code someone helped me with.

```
named_scope :shares_interest_with_user, lambda {|user| { :joins => "LEFT JOIN
              events_interests ei ON ei.event_id = Event.id " +
             "LEFT JOIN users_interests ui ON ui.interest_id = ei.interest_id",
           :conditions => ["ui.user_id = ?", user]  }}
```

When i run from the controller =>

```
  @user = User.find(1) 
  @events = Event.shares_interest_with_user(@user)
```

I get the SQL error : "no such column: Event.id:     SELECT "events".* FROM "events"  LEFT JOIN events_interests ei ON ei.event_id =..........."

Now I'm sure the event model has an id and I think I have all the column names right..can anyone see what is missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest moving away from HABTM and instead using `has_many :through`.

Here's a [great blog post](http://kconrails.com/) explaining the difference written by SO user [Jaime Bellmyer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/252014/jaime-bellmyer).